# How do you run a .exe with parameters using vba's shell()?

Tags: excel, vba, shell, parameters, command-line-arguments

I have a target file path that is structured like example below.

```
C:\Program Files\Test\foobar.exe /G
```

What I need to do is be able to execute this file using VBA's `shell()` command.

How do I have to format the file path to tell `Shell()` that there is an argument that it needs to call along with running the .exe

What I've read/tried (with no avail) is below with the results to the right.

```
file = """C:\Program Files\Test\foobar.exe"" /G"    <---Bad file name or number (Error 52) 
shell(file)

file2 = "C:\Program Files\Test\foobar.exe /G"       <---file never found
shell(file2)
```

I've succeeded with running other .exe's using shell() so I know it's not a problem with VBA or the function.

Example:

```
works = "C:\Program Files\Test\test.exe"
shell(works)
```

I'm not particularly familiar with the process involved with executing files that require additional parameters so if I misspeak or you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: This should work. However, as a workaround you can use a batch file that you create and then execute.

Comment: @Olaf. Should both of the above examples work?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This works for me (Excel 2013):

```
Public Sub StartExeWithArgument()
    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim strArgument As String

    strProgramName = "C:\Program Files\Test\foobar.exe"
    strArgument = "/G"

    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

With inspiration from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3448682.

Comment: This might also be of interest: [Run Associated Program](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18921970/2454604).

Comment: Great job, I'm having a little difficulty wrapping my head around the escaping double quotes. Would you elaborate on this? I understand you must prepend double quotes with a pair of double quotes to escape them, so adding the space in the middle I get... But I don't get the beginning and end. I get that the Shell function must be passed a string, and that placing double quotes in front of the variable would cause the variable to be treated as a string... but why 4 sets of double quotes?

Comment: @KevinScharnhorst The 4 quotes at the beginning (and end) means 'a string with one quote', and the quotes between ampersands 2 and 3 means 'a string with two quotes and a space character in between'. This meens calling the Shell function with '"C:\Program Files\Test\foobar.exe" "/G"' (without the single quotes).

Comment: This doesnt do it: "C:\Windows\System32\cacls.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\software foo\DataBase\DataBase.mdb" "/e /p Benutzer:F" any idea?

Comment: @user3305711 Make sure it runs in the command window first. Try different variations on quotation, e.g., "C:\Windows\System32\cacls.exe" ""C:\Program Files (x86)\software foo\DataBase\DataBase.mdb" /e /p Benutzer:F"

Answer (score 15):

Here are some examples of how to use Shell in VBA.
Open stackoverflow in Chrome.

```
Call Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" & _
 " -url" & " " & "www.stackoverflow.com",vbMaximizedFocus)
```

Open some text file.

```
Call Shell ("notepad C:\Users\user\Desktop\temp\TEST.txt")
```

Open some application.

```
Call Shell("C:\Temp\TestApplication.exe",vbNormalFocus)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can I ask what the significance of the vbMaximizedFocus vs. vbNormalizedFocus?  Also, how do I work in a parameter that gets called along with the file?

Comment: This just determines whether you want the program to open in a maximized window or in a normal size window. Concerning arguments I just think you do something like this: Shell (C:\SomeApplication argument1 argument 2). Also there is the ShellExecute function that provides more options to your call.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will help you to auto open the .exe file from excel...

```
Sub Auto_Open()


    Dim x As Variant
    Dim Path As String

    ' Set the Path variable equal to the path of your program's installation
    Path = "C:\Program Files\GameTop.com\Alien Shooter\game.exe"
    x = Shell(Path, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sTempBAT = "d:\tempLog.txt"    
Set shellwindows = GetObject("new:9ba05972-f6a8-11cf-a442-00a0c90a8f39")
Set itemobj = shellwindows.Item()
itemobj.document.Application.ShellExecute sTempBAT, "", "", "open", 0
```

An alternative way to call shell function
https://blog.sevagas.com/IMG/pdf/bypass_windows_defender_attack_surface_reduction.pdf