# Path of separate workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a macro as an AddIn so that it is available in any of the workbooks I open. This macro will automatically save an Excel file as a CSV file. When I open a new workbook (newwb.xlsx) and apply this AddIn, I want my code to automatically find the path where I saved this newwb.xlsx and save it in the same location.

I found online that `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` can be used to locate path itself and  `Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName` for the path with the workbook name. However, it only returns the path name of the AddIn file and not the path name of newwb.xlsx.

How do I get the file path of the new workbook file?

Here is my code:

```
'Declare the data type of the variables
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iRow As Long
Dim sFilename As String
Dim cellValue As String
Dim MyTextFile

'Set wks to the current active worksheet
Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

'Set the location of the csv file to a variable
sFilename = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName & "\newwb.csv"

'Within the current active worksheet, identify the last interested row and column of data
'Any values such as 'a', '1' or '%' are considered as values. Spaces (Spacebars) are not considered as values.
With wks
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        lastCol = .Columns.Count
        lastRow = .Rows.Count
    End With

    'Delete extra rows with blank spaces
    For iRow = 1 To lastRow
        For iCol = 1 To lastCol
            cellValue = wks.Cells(iRow, iCol)
        Next iCol

        If Trim(cellValue) = "" Then
            wks.Cells(iRow, iCol).EntireRow.Clear
            wks.Cells(iRow, iCol).EntireColumn.Clear
        End If
    Next iRow

   'Delete extra rows and columns with formats
    .Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Resize(Rows.Count - lastRow, 1).EntireRow.Clear
    .Cells(1, lastCol + 1).Resize(1, Columns.Count - lastCol).EntireColumn.Clear
    .UsedRange.Select
End With

'Save as .CSV file in the specific location stated earlier
'If there are errors in the code when Users presses 'No' for the conversion, set wks to nothing and end the process
On Error GoTo err_handler
wks.SaveAs Filename:=sFilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV

'System to/not display alerts to notify Users that they are replacing an existing file.
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Notify users that the .CSV file has been saved
MsgBox sFilename & " saved"

'Opens the CSV file in a specifc location in Notepad
MyTextFile = Shell("C:\Windows\notepad.exe ActiveWorkbook.Path & /S /K  ""\newwb.csv""", vbNormalFocus)


err_handler:
'Set Wks to its default value
Set wks = Nothing

End Sub
```

### Edit:

`Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` works at the line:

```
sFilename = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\newwb.csv"
```

but there is an error saying that the system cannot find the path in this line:

```
MyTextFile = Shell("C:\Windows\notepad.exe Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & /S /K  ""\newwb.csv""", vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: does `Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` work properly ?

Comment: Hi @iDevlop, yes it does, the code can function well in newwb.xlsx. THe only issue is the path name.

Comment: Then try `wks.Parent.FullName` ?

Comment: It works! But I cannot open the file after it is being saved. (Refer to my edit in the original question) Thanks!!

Comment: Use `sFileName` instead of recalculating the name!! That's what variables are for.

Comment: I have found the way to do it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917355/how-do-you-run-a-exe-with-parameters-using-vbas-shell . Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to run the code smoothly, in courtesy of [How do you run a .exe with parameters using vba's shell()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917355/how-do-you-run-a-exe-with-parameters-using-vbas-shell) . Hope this will help anyone in need, and I would like to appreciate my gratitude to those who have tried to help. Thanks!!

Final Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateCSV()

'Declare the data type of the variables
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iRow As Long
Dim sFilename As String
Dim cellValue As String
Dim MyTextFile
Dim strProgramName As String

'Set wks to the current active worksheet
Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

'Set the location of the csv file to a variable
sFilename = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\testing.csv"

'Within the current active worksheet, identify the last interested row and column of data
'Any values such as 'a', '1' or '%' are considered as values. Spaces (Spacebars) are not considered as values.
With wks
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        lastCol = .Columns.Count
        lastRow = .Rows.Count
    End With

    'Delete extra rows with blank spaces
    For iRow = 1 To lastRow
        For iCol = 1 To lastCol
            cellValue = wks.Cells(iRow, iCol)
        Next iCol

        If Trim(cellValue) = "" Then
            wks.Cells(iRow, iCol).EntireRow.Clear
            wks.Cells(iRow, iCol).EntireColumn.Clear
        End If
    Next iRow

   'Delete extra rows and columns with formats
    .Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Resize(Rows.Count - lastRow, 1).EntireRow.Clear
    .Cells(1, lastCol + 1).Resize(1, Columns.Count - lastCol).EntireColumn.Clear
    .UsedRange.Select
End With

'Save as .CSV file in the specific location stated earlier
'If there are errors in the code when Users presses 'No' for the conversion, set wks to nothing and end the process
On Error GoTo err_handler
wks.SaveAs Filename:=sFilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV

'System to/not display alerts to notify Users that they are replacing an existing file.
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Notify users that the .CSV file has been saved
MsgBox sFilename & " saved"

'Opens the CSV file in a specifc location in Notepad
strProgramName = "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"
MyTextFile = Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & sFilename & """", vbNormalFocus)

err_handler:
'Set Wks to its default value
Set wks = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

ActiveWorknook.Fullname works correctly for me when used from an XLA.
Note that your code

```
sFilename = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName & "\newwb.csv"
```

does not use just the path to the active workbook but the path and name of the active workbook appended with \newwb.csv

Comment: Hi. `Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName` works and it returns the path of the XLA file. However, I am not looking for this path. Instead, I am looking for the path of the newwb.xlsx file.

Comment: It returns the path of the active workbook for me when used from an XLA addin. Are you sure that you are calling the code from within the addin file and have correctly saved it as an XLA or XLAM?

Comment: Hi, yes the code managed to return the correct path with I use `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` at this line: 
    `sFilename = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\newwb.csv"`

However, it does not run at the line below, with the error saying that the system is not able to find the file.

    `MyTextFile = Shell("C:\Windows\notepad.exe Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & /S /K  ""\newwb.csv""", vbNormalFocus)`

Comment: try something like MyTextFile = Shell("C:\Windows\notepad.exe " &  Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & " /S /K ""\newwb.csv""", vbNormalFocus)

Comment: I have found the way to go about doing it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917355/how-do-you-run-a-exe-with-parameters-using-vbas-shell. Thank you so much for your help!!