# how to run my projects/softwares by only 1 click(Not double click)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, batch-file, click, ini

You know that . when you want to run your programmed projects (In windows) you'll have to double click on the icon of that app. I want to know how to run it(By programming) with only ONE  click (NOT 2)?
Should I use .ini or .bat files?
Thanks In advance...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\CCleaner"
start CCleaner64.ex

cd "C:\Program Files\Firefox"
start Firefox.exe

exit
```

You can code all the programs you want to start in a batch file. Then by double clicking the batch file it starts all of them.

copy the code into a .txt file and rename it to .bat

here is a .vba example... I got it from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917355/how-do-you-run-a-exe-with-parameters-using-vbas-shell)

```
Public Sub StartExeWithArgument()
    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim strArgument As String

    strProgramName = "C:\Program Files\Test\foobar.exe"
    strArgument = "/G"

    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", vbNormalFocus) 
End Sub
```

Comment: I said without double click - you say:""  Then by DOUBLE clicking the batch file it starts all of them.""        In addition My programming language is vba.  How can I convert it to. Bat file?

Comment: you can change your mouse settings in windows to run a program by single clicking. Go to control panel > folder options look there for the option.

Comment: Oops.  This is a great idea