# Invoke autoit from vb macro

Tags: excel, autoit, vba

I have developed an automation process using vb macro and for one part of it, I have to use the output of an auto-it script. (I am calling PDF advanced search option in this script) 
Is it possible to call an auto-it script from vb macro?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917355/how-do-you-run-a-exe-with-parameters-using-vbas-shell).

Comment: Thanks @user4157124, will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Use below:

```
 Dim runscript

 runscript = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoIt3_x64.exe C:\Test\AutoIt\testfile.au3")
```