# FollowHyperlink without prompt or open a program with prompt vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to find a get around to open a program in excel using VBA to just automatically open instead of having the prompt come up. I am doing this so it will just open my e-mail in the morning. I am on a network and it won't allow me to change anything to the startup other than the manipulation I am using for excel's open files. I have tried using the Shell function in VBA to click the button automatically and tried turning off display alerts. If that doesn't make sense I can try to reword it better, but for now this is the code I have:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ' OrderByDate Macro


     Worksheets("Main Page").Activate


     Application.DisplayAlerts = False



        Range("B4:D20").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GE Re-Release Website Lookup").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GE Re-Release Website Lookup").Sort.SortFields.Add _
          Key:=Range("B5:B20"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
          DataOption:=xlSortNormal

      With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GE Re-Release Website Lookup").Sort
         .SetRange Range("B4:D20")
         .Header = xlYes
         .MatchCase = False
         .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
         .SortMethod = xlPinYin
         .Apply
      End With



      Welcome.Show

    Call Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE", vbNormalFocus)

      'ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink`, you simply want to `Shell()` out to launch Outlook.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24143550/2344413) on how to set this up.

Comment: I was able to do it with the following code:                                                                                                    Call Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE", vbNormalFocus)

Comment: Despite its use in the answers, I don't _think_ `Call` is necessary in this situation. In general, `Call` is deprecated... Glad I was able to help!