# Running an .exe in VBA using shell

Tags: excel, vba, shell

similar to [How do you run a .exe with parameters using vba's shell()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917355/how-do-you-run-a-exe-with-parameters-using-vbas-shell)

```vb
Sub RunExe()
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    Dim errorCode As Long
    errorCode = wsh.Run("C:\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir\My.exe", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
End Sub
```

The issue I am having is that the cmd line already starts in a folder with a different path.  So when I run this code it starts down a path that I know the program is not in, I get the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 
'C:\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(String path)
   at ReadDirectory(String directory)
   at Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Is there some way to start back at c:\users?  Or clear/flush the stream?
This is where running run -> cmd.exe starts.  But for some reason I have some memory in vba and starts in a different file path.

Comment: _where running run -> cmd.exe starts_ is the Windows current directory.  You can change that using `ChDir`, eg `ChDir "C:\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir`

Comment: I suspect that's not a realistic path to your executable. By chance does the _real_ path have spaces and therefore require quotation marks or escape characters?

Comment: no spaces or weird characters. Easy enough to verify my path by running cmd from start and navigating along the path I have specified.  but given the starting point that it has when i run it form vba, I have to go back 2 folders then forward.  I don't know how to put in cd ..\ commands in the shell from vba either.  I don't know if it will always start from that random file path either.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I cannot get ChDir to compile in your example.  I have tried Call Shell("cmd ChDir C:\Users", vbNormalFocus), but this doesn't do anything I expect.

Comment: It's a VBA command - so it exactly and only `ChDir "C:\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir\dir"` (ie doesn't use Shell)

Comment: @chrisneilsen OOOHHH Eureka!